# JavaFX: Node doesn't recognize when mouse is being dragged over it

Tags: java, javafx

I'm attempting to have a node recognize when a drag gesture is performed from one node to another.
I've tried to set a MouseDragEvent through `node#setOnMouseDragOver` but it doesn't ever get invoked.

This is my implementation:

```
nfaNode.setOnMouseDragOver(event1 -> {
                System.out.println("over " + nfaNode.getText().getText());
            });
```

[image]

I want it to know that Q_1 is being dragged over so that I am able to tell that Q_0 is being dragged to Q_1.

Answer (score 0):

During a dragging gesture events are only delivered to the node where the gesture started by default. To change this, you need to call `startFullDrag` in the `onDragDetected` handler. Also if you move the node around, setting `mousetransparent` to `true` may be necessary for the mouse events not to be delivered just to the dragged node.

**Example**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(100, 100, Color.BLUE);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100);
    rect2.setFill(Color.RED);

    rect1.setOnDragDetected(evt -> {
        rect1.startFullDrag();
    });

    rect2.setOnMouseDragOver(evt -> {
        System.out.println("over");
    });

    Pane root = new Pane(rect1, rect2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment out `rect1.startFullDrag();` and you'll not see any output in the console.

**Update**

You can retrieve the `gestureSource` from a `MouseDragEvent` to get the node where you started the drag gesture and use `getSource` to retrieve the node where the event handler was added. Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField text1 = new TextField();
    TextField text2 = new TextField();

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> dragDetected = evt -> ((Node) evt.getSource()).startFullDrag();
    EventHandler<MouseDragEvent> dragOver = evt -> {
        System.out.println("over " + ((TextField) evt.getGestureSource()).getText());
    };

    EventHandler<MouseDragEvent> dragReleased = evt -> {
        TextField target = (TextField) evt.getSource();
        TextField source = (TextField) evt.getGestureSource();
        if (source != target) {
            target.setText(source.getText());
            source.clear();
        }
    };

    for (TextField tf : Arrays.asList(text1, text2)) {
        tf.setOnDragDetected(dragDetected);
        tf.setOnMouseDragOver(dragOver);
        tf.setOnMouseDragReleased(dragReleased);
    }

    VBox root = new VBox(text1, text2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: I've attempted this, using `nfaNode.setOnDragDetected(event1 -> nfaNode.startFullDrag());
            nfaNode.setOnMouseDragOver(event1 -> {
                System.out.println("over " + nfaNode.getText().getText());
            });` but the only thing ever printed is Q_0. I cannot explicitly write it as node1 and node2 because I'm adding these actions to all nodes whenever they are added to a pane.

Comment: @OrangeReceptacle use the gesture source and the source available through the event object. (Added example to answer)